# How do you count the number of negative items in a list using a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I have to make a recursive function that counts how many negative values there are in a given list, but I can't figure out what I am supposed to return for each conditional.

```
def countNegatives(list):
    """Takes in a list of numbers and
    returns the number of negative numbers
    that are inside the list."""
    count = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if list[0] < 0:
            return count + 1
        else:
            return countNegatives(list[1:])

print(countNegatives([0, 1, -1, 3, -5, 6])) # should output 2 but gives me 1
print(countNegatives([-1, -3, 50,-4, -5, 1])) #should output 4 but gives me 1
```

Comment: Think about it, your code can only return 0 or 1, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the answers provided so far will fail with a stack overflow condition if given a large list, such as:

```python
print(countNegatives([i-5000 for i in range(10000)]))
```

They all break a problem of size *n* into two subproblems of size 1 and size *n-1*, so the recursive stack growth is O(*n*). Python’s default stack size maxes out at around 1000 function calls, so this limits that approach to smaller lists.

When possible, it's a good idea to try to split a recursive problem of size *n* into two subproblems that are half that size. Successive halving yields a stack growth that is O(log *n*), so it can handle vastly larger problems.

For your problem note that the number of negatives in a list of size *n* > 2 is the number in the first half of the list plus the number in the second half of the list. If the list has one element, return 1 if it's negative. If it's non-negative or the list is empty, return 0.

```python
def countNegatives(lst):
    size = len(lst)         # evaluate len() only once
    if size > 1:
        mid = size // 2     # find midpoint of lst
        return countNegatives(lst[:mid]) + countNegatives(lst[mid:])
    if size == 1 and lst[0] < 0:
        return 1
    return 0

print(countNegatives([0, 1, -1, 3, -5, 6]))             # 2
print(countNegatives([-1, -3, 50, -4, -5, 1]))          # 4
print(countNegatives([i - 5000 for i in range(10000)])) # 5000
```

With this approach you'll run out of memory to store the list long before you would get a stack overflow condition.

Answer (score 0):

When `list[0] < 0` your code ignores the rest of the list, yet there could be more negative values there to count.

So in that case don't do:

```
        return count + 1
```

but:

```
        return 1 + countNegatives(list[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The step you were missing is to add the count to the returned value of the recursive call, so that the returned values of all recursive calls get summed up at the end. Here's one way you could do this:

```
def countNegatives(list):
    #if the list length is zero, we are done
    if len(list) == 0:
        return 0

    # Get the count of this iteration
    count = 1 if list[0] < 0 else 0
    # sum the count of this iteration with the count of all subsequent iterations
    return count + countNegatives(list[1:])
```

So, for your first example, the actual steps taken by your code would look like:

```py
return 0 + countNegatives([1, -1, 3, -5, 6])
return 0 + countNegatives([-1, 3, -5, 6])
return 1 + countNegatives([3, -5, 6])
return 0 + countNegatives([-5, 6])
return 1 + countNegatives([6])
return 0 + countNegatives([])
return 0
```

Expanding all the values gives:

```py
return 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. That means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects. We can implement using straightforward [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If the input list is empty, there is nothing to count. Return the empty result, `0`
2. (inductive) the input list has at least one element. If the first element is negative, return 1 *plus* the sum of the recursive sub-problem
3. (inductive) the input list has at least one element and the first element is positive. Return 0 plus the sum of the recursive sub-problem

```py
def countNegatives(t):
  if not t: return 0                                # 1
  elif t[0] < 0: return 1 + countNegatives(t[1:])   # 2
  else: return 0 + countNegatives(t[1:])            # 3
```

Python 3.10 offers an elegant pattern matching solution -

```py
def countNegatives(t):
  match t:
    case []:                          #1
      return 0
    case [n, *next] if n < 0:         #2
      return 1 + countNegatives(next)
    case [_, *next]:                  #3
      return 0 + countNegatives(next)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to accumulate `count`, so pass it to the recursive function. The first caller starts at zero, so you have a good default.

```
def countNegatives(list, count=0):
    """Takes in a list of numbers and
    returns the number of negative numbers
    that are inside the list."""
    if len(list):
        count += list[0] < 0
        return countNegatives(list[1:], count)
    else:
        return count

result = countNegatives([1,99, -3, 6, -66, -7, 12, -1, -1])
print(result)
assert result == 5
```